# Resharper C#, Trigger an action if test fails

Tags: c#, resharper, screenshot

Just wondering if anyone knows how to trigger an action if a test fails using resharper? I'd like the framework to take a screenshot but only if a test fails. I have the screenshot method written. I just need a way of triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

[DataCollectors](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/extensions/datacollector.md) could do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to extend your answer with more details because link only answers [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) are NOT considered as real answers.